# Performance review without me invited

Tags: management, work-environment, human-resources, performance-reviews, work-life-balance

I am working in a small tech company and have done majority of the work by myself. There are times that I worked over the weekend or till 11 pm to make sure the project would be completed on time.

There will be a performance review for me which I am not invited; the meeting will be between my manager, HR, CEO. What does that meeting mean? Any thought?

Comment: Was it a regular performance review that all employees normally have once or twice a year ?  Can you check with your coworkers discreetly to see if this is the normal practice of the company ? -- It would be very strange if this is a regular performance review and both the CEO and HR are invited while the employee is not invited there.

Comment: BTW, can you google how your company normally does the reviews ? There are many independent websites which let both current and former employees freely post honest reviews about their own companies' practices/policies along the positive and negative comments. -- One last thing : don't worry too much. Whatever it is, you can always get another job elsewhere if necessary because you are willing to work hard (as you wrote "I worked over the weekend or till 11 pm to make sure the project would be completed on time."). Good luck. :-)

Comment: Performance reviews typically have two parts, the first part is the manager tells you, what they believe your performance has been.  The second part is you tell them what your performance has been.  Between those two parts the output should be you understanding what has been work and what hasn’t been working and understanding what expectations there are going forward.  So after these two stakeholders meet, when do you meet with one of them, to discuss your performance? Your asking us what the meeting means but have you ask them?

Comment: It won't be a performance review. It will be a discussion about how much money they'll be forced to give you to keep you from leaving them. And yes, such discussions happen before the employee is brought into the discussion.

Comment: Do they know how hard you have worked to ensure deadines have been met?

Comment: This is not really what you asked about but...  Your question seems to imply that working long hours is an attribute of good performance.  In most tech jobs performance is rated on results not effort or hours.  If anything your question indicates that your performance is substandard in some way and it may be related to WHY you end up working long hours.

Answer (score 3):

It depends how you got the information.

If a colleague told you then discount it as something to be dealt with only if it actually arises.

If a manager told you, you should have asked them at the time for clarification.

In any case there is no knowing what the meeting if any is about, so don't let it stress you. You'll find out in time.

Normally if you're informed then it's either positive or you already know exactly why it's a negative thing.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds normal to me.

Your manager should be having regular meetings with you. This meeting is between management, to discuss how you are doing, and what your next pay rise should be.